# Octane > Blender Materials Import / Conversion

Tags: rendering, materials, import, octane-render-engine

I have a large file of materials saved as Octane Package Files or .orbx that make up my local materials database within Octane. I have changed my workflow and instead of Standalone Octane I've begun using Blender with the Octane plugin. SO, I cant figure out how to transfer these octane materials to blender - any ideas?